# flask app convert sql query to python plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask, plotly

i would like to convert in my flask app an SQL query to a plotly pie chart using pandas. this is my code :

```
def query_tickets_status() :
    query_result = pd.read_sql ("""
            SELECT COUNT(*)count_status, status 
            FROM tickets 
            GROUP BY status""", con = mydc_db)
    return query_result

labels_statut = query_tickets_status['status']
values_statut = query_tickets_status['count_status']

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels_statut, values=values_statut)])
graphSuppliers = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

return render_template('admin/dashboard.html', graphSuppliers = graphSuppliers)
```

this is my template file.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>Your Plotly Chart</h1>
  <div id='chart' class='chart'></div>
</body>
<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var graphs = {{graphSuppliers | safe}};
  Plotly.plot('chart',graphs,{});
</script></html>
```

but I get error in this line:

```
labels_statut = query_tickets_status['status']
```

> TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if `query_tickets_status` is a function then you can treat it as list/dictonary and use `[ ]` but you have to execute it using `( )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query_tickets_status` is a `function` but you treat it as `list`/`dictionary`/`DataFrame`.

You have to first use `()` to execute this function and later use `[ ]` to get value from `dictionary`/`DataFrame` (which this function returns)

```
result = query_tickets_status()

labels_statut = result['status']
values_statut = result['count_status']
```

---

Eventually you could use all directly without creating function `query_tickets_status()`

```
query_result = pd.read_sql ("""
        SELECT COUNT(*)count_status, status 
        FROM tickets 
        GROUP BY status""", con = mydc_db)

labels_statut = query_result['status']
values_statut = query_result['count_status']
```